# Calculating residue of $f(z)$ around $a=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Let $f(z) := \frac{3\sin 4z}{z^4}$. Find
$$\mbox{res}\left [f(z),\infty\right ]$$
For $a=\infty$, the residue is given as $-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z|=R} f(z)\mbox{d}z$.
$$\int_{|z|=R} \frac{3\sin 4\xi}{(\xi-0)^{3+1}}\mbox{d}\xi = \frac{2i\pi}{3!}g^{(3)}(0),\ \ g(z) := 3\sin 4z $$
We find that $g^{(3)}(0) = -192\cos 0 =-192$, so we have:
$$\mbox{res}\left [f(z),\infty\right ] = 32 $$

An alternative attempt:
Let $w=1/z$, Find the Laurent series of $f(1/w)$ around point $1/a=0$
$$f(1/w) = 3w^4\sin (4/w) = 3w^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\cdot\frac{4^{2k+1}}{w^{2k+1}}= 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k4^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!w^{2k-3}},\ |w|>0$$
Substituting back gives us
$$f(z) = 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k4^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}z^{2k-3},\ \ |z|<\infty\,(?)  $$
Desired residue at $k=1$ as required.

Comment: The series for the sine should have $2k+1$ in the exponents. (I didn't check whether it comes out right if you correct that.)

Comment: @joriki
Oh god (this is embarrassing)... Ok that mistake is cleared (..ish),  but still $z^{-1}$ coefficient is not what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted $w$ to $z$ twice. It's either $z^{2k-3}$ or $1/z^{3-2k}$. If you correct that, you get the right residue $32$ for $k=1$ (where you need to take the negative value of the coefficient).

Comment: such an obvious mistake :< This is extremely embarrassing. Thanks :)